# Convert if statements to if-else

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

Currently in the code of my project I have the same sentence in multiple files

```
if( exceptionString != null ){
     //Logic here
}
```

I need to update it in all files, add an else block with new tasks

```
  if( exceptionString != null ){
         //LOGIC
    }
  else{
        //NEW LOGIC
  }
```

Is there some short cut in Eclipse that I can use to do so?.

I'm thinking about doing it with linux, if eclipse does not have support for this task.

Comment: Is the logic in the if statement the same in every place that you have it? If so, this sounds like a good time to make a function with the new `if...else`. Then you just replace all of the `if` statements with a function call.

Comment: No, it is not, I understand that the best option is to optimize the current code, but, it is not an option for this moment, I have to do the correction in a massive way and without time for optimizations.

Comment: I don't know a good way to do this repeatedly throughout your source code, even with an IDE. This seems like an ideal time to figure out a way to refactor the repetition because making the change otherwise will probably take just as much time.

Comment: @matiaslopez Imagine another employee is working on that code in the future and he has to spend the time equal to your time that you need to edit all single places now. Refactoring might be an investment!

Comment: If the logic in the else statement will be different, I don't see how automation could be of much help to you? I don't even think what you want is easily automatable without refactoring too much.